# DNS Configuration for Exchange Autodiscover service

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, exchange-2013, dns-hosting, dns-zone

I need to publish the exchange service to the internet.
I need a basic help with the DNS configuration of my unique registrar service.

On the registrar site:
I configure a DNS "A" Record that reference to my enterprise public IP
exchange.myenterprise.com -> Public Static Ip of my enterprise.

It Works.

Now I've to do the same thing with the "autodiscover" service.
Have I to introduce a new DNS record type A that reference with the same public IP of my enterpise?

autodiscover.myenterprise.com -> Public Static Ip of my enterprise

Is it possible to have a multiple host that reference with the same public IP?

Can this interfere with the other DNS record (exchange.myenterprise.com) that works correctly up to now?

Note: the autodiscover service runs correctly into the enterpise LAN.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can have multiple A Records** that point to the same Public IP address and internal server. That is quite normal.

***The way to look at it is:***

Your exchange server runs both the autodiscover & the mail service so you can indeed have both pointing to the same exchange server.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Ankh2015. you have have multiple DNS records pointing to same public IP.